# How do you design different table groups in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout, tableview

So basically I want a table view to be sorted into different grouped sections (I've already changed the table view style to grouped.) But I don't know how to design different groups of the table. I know how to style the table itself and the cells, but groups are a bit harder especially considering that for my project each group needs to be very dynamic in the amount of rows it holds as well as how it is displayed. Here is a picture of what I want to accomplish here

[image]

Each box would be a different group of the table. I have two separate questions about achieving this style...

1. How do you design table groups in iOS?
2. In a project like this, where a page has many different groups of content, is it better to use a table view with many sections, or a table view where each cell contains its own table view (so each box in the picture above would be one cell of the top level table)? Or maybe there's a third option I'm not even thinking of?

EDIT:

I'm adding a different picture to this because I think I may have oversimplified the design in the picture I showed above (I have a much more complex design for an app right now but I tried to create a simpler design to highlight only the problem at hand). Here is the new picture:

[image]

Basically this new picture illustrates that I want to be able to

A. Edit the style of all of the groups of the table (rounded corners)

B. I want to be able to target a specific group and adjust it's style (different background colors)

Comment: You definitely should not use multiple table views. Use one tableview with grouped style. Most important is to correctly implement your datasource methods. But your question is quite general, I suggest you check one of thousands of tutorials on table views available out there, or specify what exactly you don't understand with your code samples.

Comment: Right now this is more of a general question about how you would go about targeting the groups of a table, and I'm not even sure where to start with that. For example, can I use interface builder, or would I need to do it in code? For that reason I don't think sample code would really add anything relevant to my question.

Answer (score 0):

You are describing the sections of a `grouped` style UITableView. For example, that's how Apple's Settings app works; both the master view and the detail view is a `grouped` table, and each "box" is a section.

Comment: If that's not good enough, I would suggest rethinking your interface. You definitely should _not_ use a table view inside a table view.

Comment: Yeah I didn't think a table view inside of a table view was right. But no I know how to set a table view to grouped. My question is how do I style different groups? Say I wanted each 'box' to have a specific spacing constraint from the edge of the screen (like in the picture) or I wanted each box to have rounded corners, or different background colors for each group, how would I go about using interface builder or code to target the style of the sections/groups on the table?

Comment: That sort of thing isn't up to you. That's why I suggest rethinking your interface entirely. For example, what about a UIPageViewController where each page is a different table view?

Comment: I haven't dealt with page views much, but it's my understanding that they require a user to swipe left and right between pages right? I want users to be able to scroll up and down through the different lists, not have to swipe between pages.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in @JoshHadik's design. Two sections each with different type of cell. Pretty straight forward. There are many ways to achieve it: e.g. create a different UITableViewCell subclass for each section, or one UITableViewCell subclass but with a type property which would set different style for the cell, you could even get away without subclassing UITableViewCell.